# .htaccess set expiry on specific folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

how do i set expiry date on specific folder.

i tried the following code, but it gives me **Internal Server Error**

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 week"

  <Directory "/var/www/mywebsite/web/js/e/">
    ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 60 minutes"
  </Directory>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says you can use `Directory` directive with `ExpireByType`, but that directive does not work in .htaccess. So you will get an error.

A couple of options here.

Maybe try your configuration this way in your Apache/VirtualHost config.

```
   <Directory "/var/www/mywebsite/web/">
   <IfModule mod_expires.c>
     ExpiresActive on
     ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 week"
     ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 week"
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
  <Directory "/var/www/mywebsite/web/js/e/">
   <IfModule mod_expires.c>
     ExpiresActive on
     ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 60 minutes"
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
```

Or you can probably just create an .htaccess file in `/var/www/mywebsite/web/js/e/` and put this in it.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 60 minutes"

</IfModule>
```